# Developing Offline Android app to open shapefiles and generate maps?

Tags: python, shapefile

I would like to create an offline Android app that can read shapefiles and generate maps as created on ArcGIS. I tend toward using Python for it.

How do I go about it?

Comment: Reading shapefiles is a matter of a hundred lines of code. Mapping like ArcGIS is closer to a million lines of code. Any way you stack it, this question is far *too broad* for GIS SE, which specializes in focused questions. Please take the [Tour] and review the [help page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for off-topic subjects.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not the best option there, but it is doable for sure.

I would suggest two libraries:

1. [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) - to build a basic mobile app
2. [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) - to visualize shapefiles (and other spatial formats)

You will also need another library to extract geometry from the shapefile, pyshp could be a good choice.

To use matplotlib with kivy you can use kivy-garden which contains all necessary bindings. Here is a simple example how to use these libraries to display the most simple plot:

```
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

class ExampleApp(App):

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box

ExampleApp().run()
```

And displaying shapefiles in matplotlib minimum example is:

```
import shapefile as shp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

your_shapefile = shp.Reader("path/to/file.shp")

plt.figure()
for shape in your_shapefile.shapeRecords():
    x = [i[0] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
    y = [i[1] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
    plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Of course there are multiple possibilities and useful features in both.